# spacing in LuaLaTeX with unicode-math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I would like to use LuaLaTeX with `unicode-math` to use some OTF math font, but when I switch on `unicode-math` the spacing in integrals looks bad. Compare the result with the legacy Computer Modern Math font

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \int_{-A}^{B} dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

with OTF Latin Modern Math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[
  \int_{-A}^{B} dx
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\setmathfont{XITS Math}` looks even worse

[image]

Is there a problem with my installation (fully upgraded TeX Live 2016 on linux, `luatex -v` gives `Version 0.95.0`) or this is the best that I should expect with `unicode-math`?

Comment: I seem to remember there were some bugs in this area, I get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyuPp.png) with xits-math with luatex 1.0.2 (and everything else from current texlive 2016)

Comment: You can  also use xelatex of course which should produce better output than you show.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a long standing bug in LuaTeX

Comment: @egreg you don't get what I show in the first comment?

Comment: FWIW, if ConTeXt gives the correct results. For example, using a similar [test file](https://gist.github.com/adityam/5075e25e988e5407c8dd017511f9d3aa) in ConTeXt, gives me [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p486C.png); with Latin Modern, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tosHh.png)

Comment: @Aditya using luatex 1?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not with LuaTeX 0.95. Possibly it has been fixed in 1.0

Comment: note your text code has `{A}` in both cases but your sample images show `-A` the image I showed is based n the code posted....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am using LuaTeX, Version 1.0.0 (TeXLive 2017/dev)

Comment: @Aditya yes I used 1.0.2 I think that's the difference: using 1.0 rather than 0.x not context/latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh sorry, I indeed generated the images with `{-A}`

Comment: @Aditya How do you installed TeXLive 2017? I could try that even if in development but I can't find anything on https://www.tug.org/texlive/. Or even just the LuaTeX package would be sufficient

Comment: @Marco: I use [ConTeXt minimals](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone), which typically includes the latest binary of luatex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I think that my output is also correct. Maybe context does something behind the scenes to fix the spacing. It has been a while since I last looked at the `.lfg` (font goodies) distributed with ConTeXt.

Comment: @Aditya yes that is what I mean: your output and my output are correct with luatex 1.0(.x) with ether context or latex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luatex had some bugs in this area but using luatex 1.0.2 (as will go into texlive 2017, or may be built from source) I get

[image]

using

```
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

You can also get essentially the same output using xelatex if that is an option.

Comment: Is there any chance at all that LuaTeX 1.0.2 will be distributed with TeXLive2016 and MacTeX2016? (Please, please, cherry on top?)

Comment: @Mico Not down to us but 'very likely no': you can get builds from W32TeX/ConTeXt minimals which work with TeX Live

Comment: David: Where is the git master (or equivalent) source code for LuaTeX? The project page only provides release versions, as far as I can tell. I can compile on Ubuntu 16.04 and regularly do that for GIMP dev version. I wouldn't mind trying LuaTeX 1.0.2 installed in /opt if possible.

Comment: you can get the texlive svn but actually I built off luatex experimental branch, `svn info` says it comes from URL: https://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/luatex/branches/experimental
Relative URL: ^/branches/experimental
Repository Root: https://foundry.supelec.fr/svn/luatex

Comment: Is it possible to install in the user local tree of TeX Live 2016 the package from TeXLive 2017 with LuaTex 1.x? Where I could find it?

Comment: @Marco it's an experimental build I compiled from source, as noted in the comment above.

Comment: Thank all of you for the answers. Before building TeXLive 2017 from source, one last try: @JosephWright I downloaded ConTeXt minimals and installed in /opt/context. In which sense it works with TeX Live? I have the new `luatex` executable in PATH, but no `lualatex` of course. When I run `latexmk -lualatex`, it still runs the TeX Live 2016 version.

Comment: @Marco copy the luatex from your texlive bin directory (just in case) and then copy the context one in to place, then run `fmtutil-sys` to rebuild the formats. the executable will detect its location and default to picking up the texlive 2016 paths